# Разные картинки на одинаковых src

Tags: html, html5, url, img

Есть url, по которому я всегда получаю разную картинку. Например https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image. Я хочу вывести на странице несколько картинок по этой ссылке, чтобы все они были разными, но они видимо кешируются браузером и в итоге я вижу одинаковые картинки:

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" />
<img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" />
```

Также пробовал поставить get-параметр:

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image?v=1" />
<img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image?v=2" />
```

...но как вы видите, результат тот же - картинки одинаковые. Какие есть варианты решения проблемы? (домен, по которому я получаю картинки ≠ мой домен).

Comment: @Akina во втором примере я как раз это и делаю (параметры v=1, v=2).

Comment: ttps://thispersondoesnotexist.com - это не ваш сайт и доступа к нему у вас нет, я вас правильно понял?

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy да, т.е. если попытаться каким-то образом через js посылать запросы то скорей всего ничего не выйдет из-за CORS политики и т.п.

Comment: Наиболее быстрый и простой способ - это связаться с разработчиком(мыло и гит можно найти на том же сайте) и прояснить с ним все вопросы напрямую. Перебирать варианты(гет параметры, роуты и тд) - сомнительный метод.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Опытным путем было выяснено, что сам сайт https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/ генерирует новую картинку примерно раз в 2 секунды (откройте ссылку одновременно в 2х разных браузерах, чтобы убедиться). Вот небольшая демонстрация.

Если мы будем слишком часто обращаться к этой ссылке, то картинки будут одинаковые (осторожно, трафик):

```js
let i = 0;
const int = setInterval(() => {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = `https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image?v=${i}`;
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    i++;
    i > 50 && clearInterval(int);
}, 100);
```

```css
img {width:50px}
```

Но если обращаться к этой ссылке раз в 2 секунды, то картинки почти всегда будут разные:

```js
let i = 0;
const int = setInterval(() => {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = `https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image?v=${i}`;
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    i++;
    i > 50 && clearInterval(int);
}, 2000);
```

```css
img {width:50px}
```

Прошу прощения у всех, кого заставил поломать голову. Главное, что теперь мы знаем, в чем было дело и когда-нибудь этот опыт нам пригодится :)